# is there any way to include load information in the tsung report

Tags: tsung

I want display the load details in tsung report file.
is there any way to add load information like :

```
<load>
   <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
       <users arrivalrate="4" unit="minute"/>
   </arrivalphase>
</load>
```

in the report.html file (in a table)